# Lavalamp and Accordion Conflict

Tags: jquery, accordion, lavalamp

I am using Accordion for my website's right menu and it works fine. I want to use Lavalamp for my main menu. When jquery.easing, my accordion does not work but I need it for Lavalamp. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this conflict !?
thanx

Comment: Can you show a live link? Also, you are bound to get some JavaScript errors. What are they?

Comment: three answers already and you didn't post a piece of code! guess I won't feel sorry for you that you are going to lose your bounty with no answer!

Comment: the problem is because LavaLamp doesn't work with last version of easing plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we need a bit more information... a demo would be ideal, and we could do with knowing exactly what goes wrong, and what error you get. It could be a compatibility issue. Are you using the latest jQueryUI? Which easing function are you using?

As a quick fix, you could try including this file: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.compatibility.js

but if that doesn't work, we really do need more information to help you fix the problem.

Comment: thank you,i have a same problem and it is solved by your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jquery-ui.min.js instead jquery.easing.js . Or sometimes this problem could result from the order of the scripts, put the easing plugin in the bottom of the page and other scripts in top for example.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could look at:

Does your Accordion menu also use jQuery?  If so, sometimes the plug-ins will combine the scripts into one.  One possibility is that the Accordion menu also has some of the jQuery.easing file pasted into it so it is conflicting.  You can look through that script and cut-out the duplicated code.

Also, make sure that the jQuery.easing script line is below your other script files.

The easiest would be to paste a link to the page for us to look at.